# В каких случаях лучше говорить "далеко от", а в каких "далеко до"?

Tags: стилистика

Интересна смысловая составляющая в контексте повествования.

> Здесь далеко от города.

> Здесь далеко до города.

Answer (score 3):

Выбор зависит от *контекста*, из которого может следовать **направление измерения расстояния**.

> Здесь далеко *от* города, поэтому тихо.

Это статический контекст, связанный с оценкой расстояния текущего местонахождения говорящего *от начала отсчета* (город).

> Здесь далеко *до* города, поэтому
> и не ездим (туда).

Этот (условно динамический) контекст связан с оценкой величины *потенциального перемещения* из точки местонахождения (начало отсчета). Расстояние поэтому измеряется в направлении от этой начальной точки *до города*.

Answer (score 2):

"Здесь" у вас не очень к месту. Можно сказать "Мы далеко **от** города" или "Это место далеко **от** города", а во втором случае "Отсюда далеко **до** города". Но во втором случае обязательна связка "от... до" ("отсюда" содержит в себе "от").

Предложения с "от города" характерны для случаев, когда кто-то ***уходит/уезжает*** из города, а вторые — для случаев ***приближения*** к нему.

Comment: "Здесь / тут" в подобных выражениях иногда встречается. Наиболее авторитетное из попавшегося — у П.Загребельного: *Тут далеко до обоих берегов, от одного отплыли так, что не вернешься, а к другому никак не пристанешь* (гуглится). Но вообще, с логикой ответа согласен.

Comment: Фраза относится к прямой речи, а персонажу можно говорить многое, и "здесь", и "тут":) И вы правы, текст изначально немного другой - "Всем здесь далеко от города, - сказала женщина и отвела взгляд в сторону". 
Спасибо